# Select values from database function in pypika

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, asyncpg, pypika

Wondering how to select data from stored function in `postgresql` DBMS by `pypika`?
Is there any function or at least possibility to run own query? For instance, `select * from get_accounts(<account_id>)`

Searched for these and didn't find any solved issue, didn't find querying from stored procedures/functions

Comment: This maybe [Functions](https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_extending.html#sql-functions-not-included-in-pypika)? `pypika` looks fairly limited in general. I would say you time would be better spent using `psycopg2` and writing queries directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve `select * from get_accounts(<account_id>)` you can simply define the stored function call as a `Function` and add it to the `from_` clause. If your `account_id` is for instance 1 you can do:

```
>>> from pypika import Query
>>> from pypika.terms import Function
>>> account_id = 1
>>> Query.from_(Function('get_accounts', account_id)).select("*")
'SELECT * FROM get_accounts(1)'
```

Comment: How is it possible to work with joins?
I have `PostgreSQLQuery.from_(accounts).left_join(account_types)`
with few other left joins and I need to connect get_account_funds function with them which has `account_id` as Parameter

Comment: I believe PyPika doesn't support selecting from functions in your desired way. You'll have to raise an issue on Github (or submit a PR). This won't be too hard to implement.

Comment: @Royalty after reading your GitHub issue I actually came up with a solution, see my edited answer. The docs/typing doesn't support it right now, but I will probably implement it like this (or very similar). Can you verify whether this works for you with your use case?